# Intersection points of series

Tags: java, jfreechart

Is it possible to find the intersection points of two series in JFreeChart? The chart series that are intersecting don't have any common points among them. So, the intersection point needs to be calculated for two series that happens to intersect each other on the graph.

```
List<Line> lineOne = one.getItems(); 
List<Line> lineTwo = two.getItems(); 
for (Line i : lineOne) { 
    for (Line j : lineTwo) { 
        if (i.intersection(j) != null) { 
            System.out.println(i.intersection(j)); 
        } 
    } 
}
```

The code above is what I was trying to do, but this throws a `ClassCastException` with this message:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ClassCastException:
org.jfree.data.xy.XYDataItem cannot be cast to
org.apache.commons.math3.geometry.euclidean.twod.Line
```

After Trashgod's suggestion I have tried doing the following:

```
List<XYDataItem> l1 = one.getItems();
List<XYDataItem> l2 = two.getItems();

Line itemOne = null;
Line itemTwo = null;
List<Line> lineOne = new ArrayList<Line>();
List<Line> lineTwo = new ArrayList<Line>();

//Add lines to the first list
for(int i = 0; i < l1.size(); i++){
    if(i < l1.size()-1) {
        itemOne = new Line(new Vector2D(l1.get(i).getXValue(),
                        l1.get(i).getYValue()), 
                        new Vector2D(l1.get(i+1).getXValue(), 
                        l1.get(i+1).getYValue()), 0);
        lineOne.add(itemOne);
    }
}

//Add lines to the second list
for(int i = 0; i < l2.size(); i++){
    if(i < l2.size()-1) {
        itemTwo = new Line(new Vector2D(l2.get(i).getXValue(),
                        l2.get(i).getYValue()), 
                        new Vector2D(l2.get(i+1).getXValue(), 
                        l2.get(i+1).getYValue()), 0);
        lineTwo.add(itemTwo);
    }
}

for(Line i: lineOne) {
    for(Line j: lineTwo) {
        if (i.intersection(j) != null) { 
            System.out.println(i.intersection(j)); 
        }                       
    }
}
```

However, while traversing through this list, it yields a lot of results (as shown in the image below) even if there are only few intersection points.
And the intersection points are not correct either.

[Image showing results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NUvje.jpg)

And my chart looks like this:
[Image for Jfreechart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3lhFB.jpg)

Please suggest the problem with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can iterate though the items comprising the [`Series`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/data/general/Series.html). As a concrete example, an [`XYSeries`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/data/xy/XYSeries.html) has a `List` of `XYDataItem` internally. Because `XYDataItem` implements `Comparable`, you can test for intersection using `equals()`. Given two series containing a single item in common,

```
private final XYSeries one = new XYSeries("One");
private final XYSeries two = new XYSeries("Two");
…
one.add(1, 1);
one.add(1, 42);
two.add(1, 2);
two.add(1, 42);
```

The following iteration scheme finds the common point, `[1.0, 42.0]`:

```
List<XYDataItem> list1 = one.getItems();
List<XYDataItem> list2 = two.getItems();
for (XYDataItem i : list1) {
    for (XYDataItem j : list2) {
        if (i.equals(j)) {
            System.out.println(i);
        }
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you can use functional operations:

```
list1.stream().forEach((i) -> {
    list2.stream().filter((j) -> (i.equals(j))).forEach((item) -> {
        System.out.println(i);
    });
});
```

> I need to find the intersection of two `XYLineChart` series which don't have common data points among them.

You can use the same iteration scheme on two instances of `List<Line>`; each list should contain the lines connecting consecutive points of the corresponding series. Replace `equals()` with a notional `intersects()` method. You can use [*line–line intersection*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line%E2%80%93line_intersection); [`Line::intersection`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/javadocs/api-3.6.1/org/apache/commons/math3/geometry/euclidean/twod/Line.html#intersection(org.apache.commons.math3.geometry.euclidean.twod.Line)) is a typical implementation.

> The code above…throws a `ClassCastException` with the message,

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ClassCastException:
org.jfree.data.xy.XYDataItem cannot be cast to
org.apache.commons.math3.geometry.euclidean.twod.Line
```

That is expected; you'll have to traverse each `List<XYDataItem>` to create the corresponding `List<Line>`. The first `Line` will be bounded by points 1 and 2; the second `Line` by points 2 and 3, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @trashgod. However, the dataset that I have doesn't have equal items in them. I need to find the intersection of two XYLineChart series which doesn't have common data points among them. So I guess I won't be able to use equals method.

Comment: I've elaborated above; please update you question to clarify this requirement.

Comment: Thanks. You said "each list should contain the lines connecting consecutive points of the corresponding series". Could you please elaborate a bit on what that means ? Any help would be great.

Comment: Line 1 is bounded by points 1 and 2; line 2 is bounded by points 2 and 3, etc.

Comment: Code in comments in hard to read; please edit your question to include a [mcve]; I've suggested an alternative above.

Comment: I've elaborated above; for further guidance, please include your [mcve].

Comment: Hey @trashgod, I have added some things I have done, are u able to give some more guidance?

Comment: Absent your [mcve], I'm guessing that you need to reject spurious intersections; try `SubLine` or simply test the result against the endpoints.